# VSCode SFTP deploy files from remote SSH server to a second remote SSH server

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, sftp

I have two remote SSH servers, server A (dev) and server B (production). When working on files on server A via SSH in VSCode, I want to be able to upload / sync files to server B using the SFTP plugin.

I can see how this is done when working on a local file system and then deploying via SFTP to a single remote SSH server, but I want to know if it's possible to deploy from one remote SSH server to another.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Jan, can you tell me for how you do it for single server. I have this usecase of intgerating sftp from local to remote server?